# Oozie distro creation failed

Tags: hadoop, oozie

I am trying to install oozie 3.3.0 and i am getting following error when i run  mkDistro.sh -DskipTests under $OOZIE_Home/bin

```
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-impl/2.2.3-1/jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Apache Oozie Main ................................. SUCCESS [1.552s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Client ............................... SUCCESS [55.093s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop 1.0.1.oozie-3.3.0 ............. SUCCESS [7.014s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop Distcp 1.0.1.oozie-3.3.0 ...... SUCCESS [0.785s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop 1.0.1.oozie-3.3.0 Test ........ SUCCESS [3.062s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop 2.0.2-alpha.oozie-3.3.0 ....... FAILURE [1.445s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop 2.0.2-alpha.oozie-3.3.0 Test .. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop Distcp 2.0.2-alpha.oozie-3.3.0  SKIPPED
```

Failed to execute goal on project oozie-hadoop: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.apache.oozie:oozie-hadoop:jar:2.0.2-alpha.oozie-3.3.0: Could not transfer artifact com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.2.3-1 from/to central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): GET request of: com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-impl/2.2.3-1/jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar from central failed: Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body (expected: 890168; received: 0 ->

Comment: I am following the instructions given in he following link to install oozie http://venkatrequiescence.blogspot.in/2012/12/oozie-installation.html

Comment: I got the same problem. Rerunning the command solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try and manually download the pom and jar from maven central and then [manually install the jars into your local repository](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/examples/custom-pom-installation.html) (both links work for me):

- [Jar Link](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-impl/2.2.3-1/jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar)
- [Pom Link](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-impl/2.2.3-1/jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.pom)

Once you've done that you can try and run the installation again